# How many elements need to be accessed in a get(x) operation in doubly linkedlist?

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

There is a question about `doubly linkedlist` that I have been thinking for a while but still cannot get the answer. Suppose there are `N` elements in a `doubly linkedlist`. How many elements do we have to access if we want to get a node in a `doubly linkedlist` both in the worst case and on average?

Intuitively, I think that the worst case is `N/2` elements because we can traverse from the front and the back of the `doubly linkedlist`. However, another thinking is that we do not know the position of the node, so we are not supposed to know which direction we should start with? If this is the thinking, the worst case is `N`. That's the point that I feel confused.

I do not know the correct result yet, probably I will update my question next week because this is one of the questions on my tutorial.

Comment: "we do not know the position of the node" - so what is x? I'd assumed you meant it was the index of the item you want to fetch.

Comment: Yes, for the WC you're right. It's `O(n)` for the reason you've mentioned

Comment: For the average case, it's `ceil(n/2)`, assuming uniform distribution

Comment: @Rup the question is quite general and it does not mention whether it will tell me the size of the `doubly linkedlist` and hence I don't know how to answer the tutorial question even if I know the index of the item.

Comment: @yaseco Thanks for your comment, I forget to consider the distribution of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re having to inspect every node to see whether it matches what you’re looking for then the worst case is N no matter what, whether it’s singly or doubly linked. Whether you start at the end, start or both ends and work in, it might well just be the case that the node you want is the last node in the list and you reach it after looking at every other node

If you had the English alphabet in a 26 node list, it just so happened that it was in order, you wanted to find z and you started at the start, you’d visit 26 nodes. Similarly if you wanted A and began at the end of the list, another 26 nodes. If you wanted M and traversed inwards from both ends, going alternately from end first, then start, you’d still visit 26 nodes

If the x is an index and your list tracks the number of items it holds then you can strategise which end to start from based on whether x is greater or less than N/2. In this scenario the worst case is Round(n/2) because for a list with an odd number of elements (eg an 11 node list) the middle node is 6 nodes in from either end and rounding up 11/2 gives 6. If you don’t know the list node count you’re worst case N (where x = the list node count) and are starting from the head of the list

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for the misunderstanding caused by my problem statement, the scenario should be that I know the position of the node that I want but I may or may not know the size of the list, so the third paragraph of your answer matches my question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single correct answer to this.   It actually depends on the way that the `get(position)` method is implemented.

- If the implentation always traverses the list in one direction (either forward or backward) then the worst case is N steps.
- If the implentation traverses the list from the one end or the other depending on the value of the position, then the worst case is N/2 steps.

But there is a catch.  In order to do it the "smart" way, the list implementation has to keep a record of the list's size.  Without this, it must calculate the size ... which involves traversing the entire list.

(Oracle / OpenJDK `LinkedList` implementations are *specified* as traversing from either end in all Java versions that I looked at.  However, you have not said if you are talking about the standard implementations.)

The average case is also not quite as straight forward as you would think.  It actually depends on the distribution function for the positions you look up.  If the distribution function is "flat"; i.e. all positions are equally probable, then the average number of steps is half of the worst case.  Otherwise ... not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think the implementation should be the standard implementation of OpenJDK. I did not consider that the distribution will influence the average number. Thanks a lot!